# unable to show a div at desired mouse location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am trying to show a div on mouseenter event at the pointer of mouse. But instead its showing div at a little distance.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.mediumListIconTextItem', function (e) {
    // $("#school").append($("#show1"));
    // $("#show1").css({'display' : 'block'});
    alert(e.pageX);
    alert(e.pageY);

    $('#show1').css({
        "top": (e.pageY),
        "left": (e.pageX),
        "background-color": "red",
        "z-index": "10",
        "position": "absolute"
    });

    $('#show1').show(); 
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.mediumListIconTextItem', function () {
    // $("#show1").css('display','none');
    $('#show1').hide();
});
```

Is there any other solution to show div at mouse enter event and at the given pointer location

Comment: Can you please show an example in a fiddle. This could be caused by `padding` or `margin` on the `body`, or the `#show1` element

Comment: I think `padding-left` and `padding-top` will help instead of just `left` and `top`...try